# $timeout function not working after a condition in if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry for the dumb question I am pretty new on AngularJS still learning it so my problem here is the $timeout function, it doesn't work after the first "window.location.href" statement and I couldn't figure out the issue. But if I put it in else statement it works but that's not where I want it. I want that when that first URL is executed, 5 seconds later the second URL executes.

```js
angular.module('Route').controller('LoginController', ['$scope', 'LoginService', '$timeout',

function ($scope, LoginService, $timeout) {
    $scope.credentials = {
        Login: '',
        Password: ''

    };
 
    $scope.login = function () {
        LoginService.login($scope.credentials)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("Response data: ", response.data);
                if (response.data.length > 0) {
                    window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/Views/home.html#!/employee";

                    $timeout(function () {
                        window.location.href="http://localhost:8080"; }, 5000);
        
                } else {
                    alert("Vérifier vos données s'il vous plâit");
                    $scope.credentials.Password = '';
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error("Error", error);
            });        
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Once you do `window.location.href = ...`, the whole page is unloaded, all JS stops running and a new page loads with new JS, so the timeout from the old page is totally killed. You might want to use ng-router or something that keeps nav in the SPA domain. If doing a full page load really is what you want, then the page you redirect to would need to set the next 5-second timer.

Comment: Angularjs is EOL since January 2022. You should use [Angular](https://angular.io/quick-start) instead. Especially if you're new to it